# Why didn't this crash?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So, I have this code :

```
int randomNumber;
int max = 16;
int swap;
int table[16];

srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    table[i] = i + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    randomNumber = rand() % max;
    swap = table[max];
    table[max] = tablica_losowa[losuj];
    table[losuj] = swap;
    --max;
}
```

Obviously, the problem should be in first pass through the second for-loop when max == 16 and I try to access table[max], but it compiled and runs fine.

This is from an iPad(newest soft) application, written in Objective-C, XCode 4.6, Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing a memory location owned by something else does not guarantee a crash, it only guarantees you're doing something you shouldn't. What will happen is depended on what the memory location is and how it is used.

The compiler is simply not doing anything to cause a problem here. Objective C is based on C... it's a little tighter in some ways but C will let you *try* to do lots of things no matter how invalid, as long as the syntax is correct. In your case, writing to table[16] *could* be writing to a memory location that isn't important. It might be writing to `swap`, which then gets overwritten. Check the assembly to be certain.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I am aware of it, but I was used to code crashing when accessing arrays out of range. Do you know if this behaviour is specific for Objective-C, iPad (memory management?) or maybe the compiler? Frankly I'm looking for a more in-depth answer, if it is possible :)

Comment: I think OP is from Java or similar kind of background, where outOfBound Exceptions are generated and gets crashed.

Comment: Losiowaty the compiler is simply not doing anything to _cause_ a problem here. I think @AnoopVaidya is correct, that your experience might be with a language where the environment forces the crash in this case? Objective C is based on C... it's a little tighter in some ways but C is a language that will let you _try_ to do lots of things no matter how invalid, as long as the syntax is correct. In your case, writing to table[16] could be writing to a memory location that isn't important. It _might_ be writing to _swap_, which then gets overwritten. Check the assembly to be certain.

Comment: Adding on @mah : Even it can write to some location where some OS's variables are pointing and that value gets changed. A funny example (however not correct) you may end up with setting your morning alarm from 6am to 11am, as you set 11 in that location.

Comment: Yes, he is correct, I remember such behaviour also from C++. If you could put your last comment (at least the part about letting me try) I will mark it as the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C (and Objective-C) does not give any guarantees regarding "undefined behavior". The array out of bounds access `table[16]` is such undefined behavior (see C11 standard 6.5.6).

This "giving no guarantees" in case of undefined behavior goes very far. Your program then is free to do anything. It could take a picture from the webcam and post it on facebook, send an offensive email to your boss and then start formatting your hard drive. Though not very likely, this behavior would be totally valid in terms of what the language says it does.

So, just ignoring the error and continuing to execute the program is obviously fine, too.